# WCF Client / Java Web Service - SOAP

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I need to send a SOAP Message with the following format (cut down from example I was given): -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:ret="http://www.another.com/ret"
                  xmlns:ser="http://www.another.com/ret/retTransaction/service"
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ser:store>
      <ret:retTransaction>
        <ret:retailTransaction xsi:type="ret:NormalTransaction">                                           <ret:applicationId>POS</ret:applicationId>   
        </ret:retailTransaction>
      </ret:retTransaction>
    </ser:store>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The operation in question is "store". That operation has an "object" parameter in the proxy following Add Service Reference.

How do I ensure that a message with the correct format is sent? Particularly the multiple namespaces in the SOAP Envelope?

Thanks

Comment: Normally you would start with a WSDL file. Do you have that?  Is that the approach you are taking?  If so, you'd use the `svcutil` tool to generate client-side proxy classes that would allow you to invoke the service. If there is no WSDL, then I suppose you could create your client-side proxy manually.